# Basic fact used in proofs in Eisenbud's commutative algebra book.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals, graded-rings

Page 31.

> **Corollary 1.5.**  *Let $k$ be a field, and let $S = k[x_1, \dots, x_r]$ be a polynomial graded by degree. Let $R$ be a $k$-subalgebra of $S$.  If $R$ is a summand of $S$, in the sense that there is a map of $R$-modules $\varphi: S \to R$ that preserves degrees and takes each element of $R$ to itself, then $R$ is a finitely generated $k$-algebra.*
>
> *Proof.* Let $\hat{m} \subset R$ be the ideal generated by the homogeneous elements of $R$ of strictly positive degree.  Since $S$ is Noetherian, the ideal $\hat{m}S$ has a finite set of generators, **which may be chosen to be homogeneous elements $f_1, \dots, f_s$ of $\hat{m}$.**  We shall show that these elements generate $R$ as a $k$-algebra.

Why is the bolded part true?

Comment: If $f\in I$ and $I$ is homogenous, then the homogeneous parts of $f$ are in $I$.  To prove it, write $f$ as a linear combination of the homogeneous generators of $I$ and group the parts together.  So, if you have a finite set of generators for $I$, you can take the homogeneous parts of each generator, and those generate the same ideal.

Comment: EnjoysMath: Since a tag you have created is [currently discussed on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27598/what-is-the-homogeneous-elements-tag-supposed-to-be-used-for), I thought that it might be useful to let you know about that.